# how much times Firebase Auth takes to consider a user that is new or not in the UserCredentail.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have this block of code:

```
  final cred = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email,
    password: password,
  );
  print(cred.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser);
```

as you see, it's a sign-in usual method from the Firebase auth.

in the `cred.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser`, it seems it returns a bool based on of the user is new or not.

but what's the date range that it considers a user is new or not, I mean how long the Auth service takes to say that the user is now not new?

I checked it's documentation from the API and all I found is:

> Whether the user account has been recently created.

and it doesn't give details about how much time it takes so the user is not new!

Comment: I think it depends on users internet speed

Answer (score 1):

Simply, when you sign in with an email for the first time `isNewUser = true`.

Otherwise `isNewUser = false`